# How can I use a Class to determine if it inherits from another class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I only have a mapping of Class strings to use to determine if the Class that the string represents inherits from another Class. I know I can use isKindOfClass on instances of objects, but I don't know how I can use a Class. So I'm trying to do something like...

```
NSString *className = [self.classMapping objectForKey:key];
Class class = NSClassFromString(className);
if (/* class inherits from ClassA */) 
    ClassA *classA = [[ClassA alloc] initWithClassAInitializer];
else if (/* class inherits from ClassB */)
    ClassB *classB = [[ClassB alloc] initWithClassBInitializer];
```

...but I don't know what goes in the if statements. How can I use a Class to determine if it inherits from another class?

Thanks in advance for your wisdom!

Comment: Try checking with `isKindOfClass`.

Comment: Try `isSubclassOfClass:`.

Comment: Maybe better it would be better idea to use NSClassFromString method.

Comment: @matt - But what are you testing when you perform `isKindOfClass` on an instance of class Class?

Answer (score 0):

These checks are unnecessary, you can simply call `alloc` on the class itself and you will get the desired init.

```
Class class = NSClassFromString(className)

id object = [[class alloc] init];
```

id here can be replaced with whatever your root class is that all of these classes inherit from. Your subclasses should all use a common init method if possible, providing any additional functionality to super init in their own init. This will allow you to avoid having to make these checks.

Answer (score 0):

As was noted in the comments, you can use the `NSObject` inheritance methods on a class object. You can also compare class objects for equality directly:

```
Class c = NSClassFromString(className);
if( c == [ClassA class] ){
    /* create instance of ClassA */
}
else if ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way: `Class` is an object, so you can do:

```
NSLog(@"%d", [[@"Test" class] isSubclassOfClass:[NSString class]]);
NSLog(@"%d", [[@"Test" class] isSubclassOfClass:[NSObject class]]);
NSLog(@"%d", [[@"Test" class] isSubclassOfClass:[NSArray class]]);
```

You can also solve this with the low-level Objective-C runtime functions:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

BOOL isClassSubclassOf(Class classToTest, Class maybeParentClass)
{
    do {
        if (classToTest == maybeParentClass) {
            return YES;
        }

        classToTest = class_getSuperclass(classToTest);
    } while (classToTest != NULL);

    return NO;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    @autoreleasepool{
        NSLog(@"%d", isClassSubclassOf([@"Test" class], [NSString class]));
        NSLog(@"%d", isClassSubclassOf([@"Test" class], [NSObject class]));
        NSLog(@"%d", isClassSubclassOf([@"Test" class], [NSArray class]));
    }
}
```

Last but not least, you might also be able to use ducktyping if the initializer names are different/unique:

```
Class klass;
id obj = nil;

klass = [NSString class];
// klass = [NSArray class];

if (class_getInstanceMethod(klass, @selector(initWithFormat:))) {
    obj = [[klass alloc] initWithFormat:@"It's string-like!"];
} else if (class_getInstanceMethod(klass, @selector(initWithObjects:))) {
    obj = [[klass alloc] initWithObjects:@"It's", @"array-like", nil];
}

NSLog(@"%@", obj);
```

As is, you'll get the log message `It's string-like!`, but if you uncomment the commented line you'll get `( "It's", "array-like" )` instead.